# how to submit form without a name for the button using jsoup post request

Tags: java, android, jsoup, forms, html-post

I'm trying to POST data into a website to make a login into the site using Jsoup. This is the html form:

```html
    <form action="/user/login" method="POST">
    <table>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="email">E-Mail:</label></td>
      <td><input name="email" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="password">Passwort:</label></td>
      <td><input name="password" type="password" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="submit" value="Login" /></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

Here is my code:

```
 Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup.connect(LOGINWEBSITE)
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0")
                    .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                    .execute();


            Document login = Jsoup.connect(LOGIN_URL)
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0")
                    .data("cookieexists", "false")
                    .data("email", email)
                    .data("password", password)
                    .cookies(loginForm.cookies())
                    .post();
```

But it doesn't work. For another website I just needed to add a line for the button and it worked. Here it does not work, since the button has no name.
Basically I want to know how to submit the from.
How can I resolve this issue?
Many thanks.

Comment: What did you try so far? Where is the problem? Please more exactly what you expect to happen.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to stackoverflow, so I accidentally posted my question before I was finished. Edited now though

Comment: If your question is solved, then you may consider accepting my answer, if if helped you finding the solution. If the solution was something different you may create your own answer here and accept that after some waiting time. This will tell others that this problem is solved and does not need any more attention. When you have a little more reputation, you can also start up- and downvoting answers and questions. I hope you will have a great time here on SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Often you need to access the login page with a `GET` request first to get all needed cookies/tokens for the post request. I can't check that for you since you did not mention the URL to which you try to connect. In your place I would record the network traffic with the browser developer tools when you manually login. Then analyze the data that actually was sent back and forth. Usually you can easily identify the necessary tokens/cookies that need to be passed along with the post request for a successful login.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I'm sorry for not giving enough information, but I have checked for everything you mentioned. I managed to resolve my problem now by removing ".data("cookieexists", "false")" from the request.